Definable closure has the exchange property in an o-minimal structure
I'm having some trouble understanding the following proof from Macpherson's Notes on o-Minimality and Variations:

Theorem 2.2.2 [Pillay and Steinhorn 1986]. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be o-minimal, $A\subseteq M$, and $b, c\in M$. If $\DeclareMathOperator{\dcl}{dcl}b\in \dcl(Ac)\setminus \dcl(A)$, then $c\in \dcl(Ab)$.
Proof. We may suppose the base set $A =\emptyset$ (by adding constants for elements of $A$ to the language), so that $b\in \dcl(c)\setminus \dcl(\emptyset)$. There is a $0$-definable (partial) function $f\colon M\rightarrow M$ with $b = f(c)$. We apply the Monotonicity Theorem to $f$. Since $b\notin \dcl(\emptyset)$, $c$ lies in the interior of an open $0$-definable interval $I$ on which $f$ is strictly monotonic. Now $J := f(I)$ is $0$-definable, and since $c := f|^{−1}_{J}(b)$, $c\in \dcl(b)$.

Namely:

I don't get how $b\in \dcl(c)\setminus \dcl(\emptyset)$ implies the existence of a $0$-definable function $f\colon M\to M$ with $c\mapsto b$.
Why does $b\notin \dcl(\emptyset)$ imply that $c$ lies in the interior of an open $0$-definable inteval?

Assuming that these two I was able to understand the rest of the proof fully.


If $b\in{\rm dcl}(b)$ the there is a formula $\psi(x,y)$ such that $\psi(c,b)\wedge\exists^{=1}y\ \psi(c,y)$. Then the formula defining $f$ is $[\psi(x,y)\wedge\exists^{=1}y\ \psi(x,y)] \vee y=c$.



is this not an immediate consequence of the monotonicity theorem? (If $f$ is constant in an interval then its value is in acl$\varnothing$.)


@Escherica so regarding the 1st point, the function $f$ that you defined maps all $M$ to $c$, because for all $x \in M$, $(x,c)$ satisfies the formula, or am I missing something?

I'm sorry, I did not write correctly what I have in mind. I try again in an answer.


If $b\in{\rm dcl}(c)$ then there is a formula $\psi(x,y)\in L$ such that $\psi(c,b)\wedge\exists^{=1} y\ \psi(c,y)$. Then the required function $f(x)=y$ is defined by (after the correction of Alex) $\psi(x,y)\wedge\exists^{=1} y\ \psi(x,y)\vee[\neg\exists^{=1} y\ \psi(x,y)\wedge x=y]$.

Follows from the monotonicity theorem by noting that there are finitely many values of $f$ where it is not locally monotonic. Therefore, these values are all in acl($\varnothing$) and in o-minimal structures acl=dcl.



Thank you. I corrected 1, and rephrased 2.

@AlexKruckman I do not understand why "partial". The function $f$ can be made total (or am I missing something?)

Yes, you're right - any partial definable function $M\to M$ can be made total by extending by the identity outside of the domain. This trick is not available for partial functions $X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are distinct sorts or disjoint definable sets.
